# Revenue Scheduling and Collaborative forecasting

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, product, forecasts-collaborative

I was working on **Product Revenue Scheduling** and I have hit a road-block. My Org uses "**Collaborative forecasting**" and I am not able to configure the forecasting to reflect the schedules.

It displays the forecast always with respect to the Opportunity Close Date. i.e. If I have 3 product schedules
$10,000 for August 2015
$10,000 for August 2016
$10,000 for August 2017
The forecast always shows $30,000 for August 2015 (instead of $10,000)

*Note-1:* I was able to configure the Customizable forecasting to reflect the schedules but we cannot move from Collaborative to Customizable forecasting.

Is there an alternative to make this work?

*Note-2:* Presently, we are considering an alternative where we will create new Opportunities with different Close Dates and split the revenue amongst them. I would like to know if there is a better/elegant way.

Thanks in advance!